# zone transfer between NSD machines without adding zone name to slave machine

Tags: domain-name-system, nsd

I have added my 'example.com' to master nsd machine with records within the zone file. Now i want to setup a slave nsd machine, is it possible to transfer the zone records without adding the zone name to 'nsd.conf' in slave machine? I mean if I add a new zone name to master nsd.conf, will it be transferred to slave nsd.conf automatically?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: IvDo you mean DNS?

Comment: no, i mean the dns server software NSD from NLnet Labs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer, if this is for DNS, is NO.  You'll have to configure the slave to handle the new zone, this does not happen automatically.

Remember of course to include the slave in the NS records for the zone in the master.

Answer (score 1):

Update 9 years later:

Nowadays it is possible, though not by regular zone transfers.

NSD has something called a control-channel. It's a client app (nsd-control) that talks to your NSD server on port 8952 (when invoked remotely) or locally through a domain socket (usually /run/nsd/nsd.socket). The specific command is

```
nsd-control addzone <zonename> <pattern>
```

You can add the NS and other records by the regular zone updates.

See https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/nsd/nsd-control/ for more info.